# PageFactory implementation from selenium for python

Tags: python, selenium

I was trying to use PageFactory from selenium in python. Can someone help me in getting the import modules or where to find it so that I can move ahead. I looked for it on the internet but no result. In fact some are even saying there is no PageFactory implementation from selenium for python. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

From the Selenium user group:

SimSel
5/7/12

Hi,

I have seen a similar message posted about a year ago. Still wanted to 
confirm if there is a pagefactory implementation in Python or plans of 
making one?

Thanks, 
S

Luke Inman-Semerau
5/7/12

I don't think one is in the works by anyone on the dev team. Feel free to submit a patch and/or log a new issue for it in the issues list
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list
- show quoted text -

Answer (score 0):

There is Python library which provides page factory approach to implement page object model in selenium -

[selenium-page-factory](https://selenium-page-factory.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)